# Populate a file field on edit form

Tags: 6, forms

I need to populate the file field with a value from the database (when editing a database row).

This is the code for the file field.

```
$form['file'] = array(
'#type' => 'file',
'#title' => t('Image'),
'#description' => t('Upload a file, allowed extensions: jpg, jpeg, png, gif'),
);
```

The variable `$icon` contains the value (e.g. icon.png).

In Drupal 7 I made this work with:

```
  '#type'         => 'managed_file',
  '#description'  => t('Icon file may be a jpg, bmp, gif or png format.'),
  '#default_value' => $default_icon,
```

How can I do this in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this

```
if ($form_state['storage']['file'] != '0') {
  $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
  ));

  // If the file passed validation:
  if (isset($file->filename)) {
    // Move the file, into the Drupal file system
    if (file_move($file, $file->filename)) {
      // Update the new file location in the database.
      drupal_write_record('files', $file, 'fid');
      // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
      $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }

  $file = $form_state['storage']['file'];
  // We are done with the file, remove it from storage.
  unset($form_state['storage']['file']);
  // Make the storage of the file permanent
  file_set_status($file, FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
}

$fid = $file->fid;
$icon = $file->filename;

if (!isset($fid)) { 
  $fid = $form['fid']['#value']; 
}

if (!isset($icon)) { 
  $icon = $form['icon']['#value']; 
}

$id = $form['id']['#value'];
$url = $form['url']['#value'];
$title = $form['title']['#value'];
```